# Android Emulator (AVD) too slow in Ubuntu run inside Virtual Machine (VMWARE Workstation)

Tags: android, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware, android-virtual-device

Can anyone suggest the way to improve the speed of Android Emulator (AVD) run in Ubuntu 14.04 inside Virtual Machine (VMWare Workstation). It's too slow happened to wait around a hour but with vain it still got loaded, but the home screen didn't turn up.

Is there any technique/trick to speed up the same via some configuration changes either in Ubuntu or with virtual machine settings.

Comment: Two Level of virtualization is hard on any computer... nevertheless check out [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Did you install it with the default settings? If so, you probably need to add some RAM and processor/cores. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this https://www.genymotion.com instead of default emulator